# How can I add style to div in asp.net code behind without runat="server"

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to set div style without runat="server" but I dont know how can i do.

```
 <div class="form-horizontal" id="editQuestionForm"> 
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="form-horizontal" id="editQuestionForm" style="{your style here}">` => is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a protected variable in your code behind and set that variable from your code.

For example - In code behind (.aspx.cs) -

[image]

In markup (.aspx) -

[image]

Comment: looks good as only the classname is the server side property. just ensure that it's not null at initialization